# Writing a text into flow file using execute script processor in Nifi

Tags: python, apache-nifi, jython

I have a data in a website(which unfortunately couldn't be fetched using invokeHTTP). I am trying to fetch the data using a execute script processor.Here is what I have done in python.tried things in comments

```
#import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64
import httplib
#import requests
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import OutputStreamCallback
import json
from datetime import datetime
from java.lang import Object
from jarray import array
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil

class WriteContentCallback(OutputStreamCallback):

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content_text = content

    def process(self, outputStream):
        try:
            outputStream.write(StringUtil.toBytes(self.content_text))
        except Exception as error:
            objArray = [error]
            javaArray = array(objArray, Object)
            log.error('Error processing the .csv file ===> {}', javaArray)
            raise ValueError


try:
    flowFile = session.create()
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url_domain)
    conn.request("GET", url)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    #outputStream.write(StringUtil.toBytes(data))
    #outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(out))) 
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback(data))
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
except Exception as outermost_error:
    objArray = [outermost_error]
    javaArray = array(objArray, Object)
    log.error('Error processing the .csv file ===> {}', javaArray)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
```

The issue seems to be there are no errors as such...but the file doesnt show up(0 bytes) and the type is application/octetstream.What can I do to get the output from the website using execute script

Here is the nifi flow, the flow has been marked in yellow.

[image]

Let me know if you need any other details. the code seems to work as jython program.And also if i pass some random text in place of data,that works too.

Comment: You have input queue but you are not reading input file. I don't see you are assigning variable url. Check what you have in a failure queue because you are writing file into it. If you don't see error in log file then I would suggest to remove try-except and let nifi to process exception in a right way.

Comment: Try-except inside process has undeclared variable ValueError.

Comment: I have provided the url...simply hid it..